# Setting access backcolor using variable color name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am pulling colors from a database field and I want that column to determine the color of a control on a form. So I know I can do this to statically set back color:

```
Me.txtPartNum.BackColor = vbRed
```

Now, I have a color red in my database so I tried doing:

```
Me.txtPartNum.BackColor = "vb" + varMyColor
```

> However, this results in Run TIme error '13' Type Mismatch

How do I use variable colors to set the background color of forms or controls in a form.

Comment: `vbRed` is equivalent to `255`, i.e. `vbRed` is not the same thing as `"vbRed"`. I'd create a helper function here to parse the color stored as text, i.e. "red", and return the equivalent color constant.

Comment: But the color is entered by a user. Is there a place where I can get a list of colors codes equivalent to these constants. Are these constants hexadecimals. I can setup my database column to store hexadecimal numbers instead.

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/color-constants).

Comment: I ended up using the solution I posted

Answer (score 0):

I ended us using this function which gives vbcolor values from hex values:

```
Function HexToLongRGB(sHexVal As String) As Long
    Dim lRed As Long
    Dim lGreen As Long
    Dim lBlue As Long

    lRed = CLng("&H" & Left$(sHexVal, 2))
    lGreen = CLng("&H" & Mid$(sHexVal, 3, 2))
    lBlue = CLng("&H" & Right$(sHexVal, 2))

    HexToLongRGB = RGB(lRed, lGreen, lBlue)

End Function
```